# Firebase Functions Accessing Firestore error: Could not load the default credentials

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been attempting to get to the bottom of issues with a Firebase function I'm using to update some aggregate data in Firestore. I set up a simple test bed and found that any attempt to access the data triggers the error:

```
>  Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
>      at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/Users/michael/Documents/htdocs/vue/mjf20/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:160:19)
```

I've attempted to just copy the entire Firebase config into the initializeApp() function, but it still generates the same error. Here's the entire test code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.postCache = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log("Starting test function");
    db.collection('myCollection').doc('myDoc').get()
    .then(snap => {
        if (!snap.exists) {
            console.log('Document not found');
        } else {
            console.log(snap.data());
            response.send(snap.data());
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('In catch block');
        console.log(error);
        response.send(error);
    });
});
```

If I take out the db stuff, the function will work fine. As soon as I add even the simplest firestore request, it generates the error. I've seen this issue asked about before, but the situations seem different, and none of the solutions seems to work. I'm stumped.

Comment: I suggest doing a web search for that error message.  You'll find a lot of the same thing.

Comment: Try importing the `firebase-admin` before the `firebase-functions` ---- `const admin = require('firebase-admin'); const functions = require('firebase-functions');`

Comment: Unfortunately, moving the firebase admin import doesn't affect the outcome. As noted, I've already done numerous searches for this error, and not found any proposed solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

The code is perfectly fine.

I have implemented it exactly on my testing project using this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

I have added your code to `index.js` and in my firestore I have added collection `myCollection` with `myDoc` with just one testing field and deployed using `firebase deploy`.

Everything works fine. You should focus on your environment and deployment steps to figure out what is the problem. This [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) that you have in the error is mentioning environment variables. Maybe a case as well.

I hope it will help!

[image]